# Trying out a foreach statement

Tags: php, html

What I'm attempting to do is make a foreach out of the following array so that each of the user roles can be an HTML option inside of a select. I am also trying to attempt to have an option pre-selected if the user being edited.

User Roles Array

```
Dump => array(5) {
    [0] => object(stdClass)#26 (2) {
        ["user_role_id"] => string(1) "1"
        ["user_role_name"] => string(5) "Guest"
    }
    [1] => object(stdClass)#27 (2) {
        ["user_role_id"] => string(1) "2"
        ["user_role_name"] => string(11) "Public User"
    }
    [2] => object(stdClass)#28 (2) {
        ["user_role_id"] => string(1) "3"
        ["user_role_name"] => string(9) "Moderator"
    }
    [3] => object(stdClass)#29 (2) {
        ["user_role_id"] => string(1) "4"
        ["user_role_name"] => string(13) "Administrator"
    }
    [4] => object(stdClass)#30 (2) {
        ["user_role_id"] => string(1) "5"
        ["user_role_name"] => string(20) "Master Administrator"
    }
}

<?php
dump_exit($user_roles);
foreach($user_roles AS $key => $value)
{
    foreach ($value AS $role)
    {

    }
    //echo '<option value="'.$key.'"'. $value->user_role_id == $key ? " selected=\"selected\"":"".'>'.$value->user_role_name.'</option>';
}
?>

UPDATE: 
I need it to see if $user_account object is present on the page because if it is that means that the user is being edited and I need it to match the user's current user_status_id with the option that fits in the dropdown.

Dump => object(stdClass)#31 (13) {
    ["user_role_id"] => string(1) "5"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to complete the answer above me, version with preselected role.

```
if(isset($user_account)) $selected= $user_account->user_role_id;
else $selected = null;
echo '<select>';
foreach ($user_roles as $role) {
    echo "<option value='{$role->user_role_id}'";
    if($role->user_role_id==$selected) echo 'selected';
    echo ">{$role->user_role_name}</option>"; 
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Plus I"m coming up with a syntax error with your great answer.

Comment: i let the braces in the if statement, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
echo '<select name="user_role">';
foreach($user_roles as $role) {
    echo "<option value='{$role->user_role_id}'>{$role->user_role_name}</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```